# Handling Paypal transactions as a third party, not sender or recipient

Tags: paypal

I need to be able to initiate transactions between two unknown parties via Paypal, say donor and recipient, without ever having to be exposed to the money itself - is this possible?

Basically, I want a donor to be able to click the donate button, fill in the amount and then be passed to Paypal to verify their details.  My site will also supply the recipients account details to Paypal so the money goes directly to them rather than to my Paypal account.  Essentially I want to enable transactions without having any legal or tax responsibilities for the money.

This needs to happen for an unlimited number of donors and recipients.

Can I do this? Paypal haven't been very helpful at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sorry to hear that you feel PayPal hasn't been helpful at all, but there are many resources at your disposal. It sounds like you have just not been asking the right person, or asking the right questions. Customer service for large corporations are difficult to traverse, but there are many people at PayPal who would have been easily able to answer your questions.

I always say this, though i'm not sure how many times on this forum: *It is possible to do whatever you want with PayPal. Give me your idea, I will give you the way. Whatever you want to do can be done with the right coding.*

You can use [Website Payments Standard (WPS)](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf), and you would only need your merchant's email address to create buttons that go to their account. (set the business variable)

You can also use third party API calls for [Website Payments Pro (WPP)](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/JP/ja_JP/files/developer/PP_WPP_IntegrationGuide.pdf) and [Express Checkout (EC)](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_ExpressCheckout_IntegrationGuide.pdf) to process direct credit card transactions as well as PayPal payments via API for your merchants. (set the subject variable to the seller you're submitting the API on behalf of)

As for not having any legal or tax responsibilities for offering the service of payment connectivity (marketplace functionality) between sellers and merchants: IMHO you are dreaming. However, you will want to contact your local legal and tax representative to ask what liability you have. Though this should go without saying; this is StackOverflow, where you should ask questions regarding programming, not tax and legal advice.

Your tax and legal concerns are separate concerns, irrelevant to the technical question of whether it is possible to do what you want with PayPal or not.

Comment: In summary; in 10 seconds, I can come up with 5 different ways to do this in PayPal. So yes, it's definitely possible.

Comment: SgtPooki / Robert - in the scenario above would it be possible to know (as the third party) if the transaction actually went through rather than only that it was initiated?

Comment: @Filip, Yes it is certainly possible. You have many options. 1) Have the merchant (receiver of the transaction) to grant you API permission so you can submit API calls to check whether a transaction is complete or not. 2) Send an IPN URL so you will get a notification from PayPal when the payment is complete. 3) use EC so you know immediately whether the payment is complete or not. 4) use the return URL and RM=1 or RM=2 to get information about the transaction when the user is returned to your site.

Comment: @SgtPooki Thanks! I'll be researching your suggestions to see if they fit my usage scenario :)

Comment: Point (1) from @SgtPooki comment described here: [PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/ht_permissions-invoice/)

Comment: As of 2017, you can now set the payee on the Payments REST API: https://devblog.paypal.com/setting-payee/

Hopefully this helps anyone looking for an up-to-date answer.